# ODBC connector access denied for user with ALL privileges

Tags: mysql, odbc

I'm trying to "Test" an ODBC Connector 5.3 and its giving me the ol' "access denied for user [username]@localhost (using password: YES)". However, when I look at the user tables, I see `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO [username]@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION`.

I feel like all privileges should be granted by that line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error, as MySQL access is restricted by client host combined with the username & password credentials, and access has to be specifically granted as detailed in [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-connecting.html).  Note that `localhost` is a special case, which is not addressed by your wildcard `GRANT` --

> If you cannot figure out why you get `Access denied`, remove from the `user` table all rows that have `Host` values containing wildcards (rows that contain `'%'` or `'_'` characters). A very common error is to insert a new row with `Host='%'` and `User='some_user'`, thinking that this enables you to specify `localhost` to connect from the same machine. The reason that this does not work is that the default privileges include a row with `Host='localhost'` and `User=''`. Because that row has a `Host` value `'localhost'` that is more specific than `'%'`, it is used in preference to the new row when connecting from `localhost`! The correct procedure is to insert a second row with `Host='localhost'` and `User='some_user'`, or to delete the row with `Host='localhost'` and `User=''`. After deleting the row, remember to issue a [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-privileges) statement to reload the grant tables. See also [Section 6.2.6, “Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html).